# Why DirectoryIterator access this path folder I define, but instead accessing the parent?

Tags: php, nginx

I am running a homebrew install of php and nginx. My root web directory is /var/www. Inside that I have a folder with a bunch of files:

```
rmp:~ rmp$ cd /var/www/somefolder
rmp:somefolder rmp$ ls
//lists all the files
```

I made a script to loop through the directory and do something with the files:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname('/var/www/somefolder/'));

foreach ($dir as $fileinfo) {
    if (!$fileinfo->isDot()) {
        var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
    }
}
```

Instead of getting all the filenames in *somefolder/* folder, I'm getting a list of files in */var/www*

I thought that it's strange, so I tried a relative path instead, since my script is in a folder paralell to *somefolder* I tried path:

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(dirname('../somefolder/'));
```

Again, contents of */var/www*

The problem seems elementary. Making me feel really stupid.

I thought maybe the server thinks I'm in a different directory? I tried `echo getcwd()` and got `/private/var/www`

So I also tried everything with absolutes with private prepended as well. Still the same. What have I missed?

Here's the weird thing, if I make the path:

```
/var/www/somefolder/somefolder
```

Then it works!? It shouldn't. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to look up what dirname() actually does here http://docs.php.net/dirname  ;-)

Comment: @VolkerK LOL! wtf. Why would it do that!?? I feel even more stupid now. But that is so counter intuitive. Why wouldn't that function be called parentdir()? My bad. Shouldn't make assumptions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because dirname('/var/www/somefolder/') result is '/var/www',you can test it.